# Magento 2 - Import CSV without duplicating images

Tags: csv, magento, import, duplicates, magento2

Does anybody know how to import CSV of multiple products to Magento 2 without duplicating images? I have been searching for a while and have only found fixes for this issue on Magento 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are importing the same CSV multiple times, I am guessing you are modifying the CSV data due to some product data not being correct on initial import?
I would remove the image column data until you are happy with the import, then include the image data in the CSV last and import again.

You could also find/override the importer class and add a image filename based check before updating a products assigned images. Given the different import options (update/replace), I would also check these and limit the check to 'update' method maybe...

Answer (score 1):

This is a known core bug in Magento 2.2+

Github issues here:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14398
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21885

And pull requests here:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21146
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21855

I'm using the first PR successfully in production, and patched using cweagans/composer-patches after every `composer install`.

Keep in mind both PRs have limitations and haven't been tested properly.